# Is locally Lipshitz mapping on a compact set globally Lipschitz?

Tags: analysis

Let $f: K \rightarrow \mathbb  R$ be a locally Lipschitz mapping on a compact subset $K$ of $\mathbb R^n$. Is it then $f$ Lipschitz?

Comment: What do you expect, and why?

Comment: I mean: Do you expect that $f$ will be Lipschitz, or don't you? Why do you expect what you expect?

Comment: Each point  $x\in K$ has a neighbourhood $U_x$ on which $f$ is Lipschitz. Such sets cover $K$. By compactness a finite numbers  $U_{x_i}$ covers $K$.On each $U_{x_i}$ $f$ is Lipschitz. Maybe $f$ is Lipschitz on their union?

Comment: @user172903 Yes, that works. You need to fill in details, of course. Another way of proving it is given in one of the answers of the duplicate.